# $(document).ready and Window onload causing events to fire twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to fix a bug in my rails 3.2.13 app where whenever I have a document ready or a window onload called, certain click events are fired twice. It only seems to happen after I fire an ajax call. If I stash the commit, then add the code back without the ajax call it works. The only way I can stop it is removing the document ready from the JS file, but I need it for some JQuery to work properly. I think it might be an issue with the asset pipeline but not sure.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.first_panel_photos').fadeIn('slow');

var ajax;
var user_kits = [];
var photo_load_batch_html;
var kits_added = 0;



$.get('/get_kits', function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        photos = data[i].photos;
        links = [];
        for (var n = 0; n < photos.length; n++) {
            link = data[i].photos[n].photo_url;
            links.push(link);
        }
        user_kits.push(new Kit(data[i].kit_name, links));
        kit_to_add = $('<button class="btn btn-info added_kit" id=' + (kits_added - 1) + '>Kit</button>');
        $('.cart').append(kit_to_add.fadeIn());
        update_total_price();

    }

});




//Listeners
$('.first_panel_photos').on('click', 'img', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    add_to_kit(this.src);
    if ($('.kit_photos_row_3').find('img').length === 3 && $('.buybtn').find('button').length === 0) {
        $('.buybtn').append($('<button class="btn btn-info add_to_cart">Add to cart</button>').fadeIn());
        $('.buybtn').append($('<input type="text" class="kit-name" placeholder="name the kit">').fadeIn());
    }
});

$('.kit_photos_row_1, .kit_photos_row_2, .kit_photos_row_3').on('click', 'img', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    remove_from_kit(this, function (img_row) {
        if ($(img_row).hasClass('kit_photos_row_1')) {
            shift_photo_from_class('.kit_photos_row_2', function () {
                shift_photo_from_class('.kit_photos_row_3');
            });
        } else if ($(img_row).hasClass('kit_photos_row_2')) {
            shift_photo_from_class('.kit_photos_row_3');
        }
    });
    if ($('.add_to_cart').length !== 0) {
        $('.add_to_cart').remove();
        $('.kit-name').remove();


    }
});
});
```

Comment: You've included a lot of code.  Could you cull out the code that isn't applicable to the problem?

Comment: Challenging code format and confusing variable names can do that to you.  Try pasting the code into a fiddle and (perhaps repeatedly) clicking "TidyUp" and "JSHint" to see if that helps as you clear the suggestions.

Comment: all hail the spagetti monster!

Comment: Thanks @MarkSchultheiss, Cleaned it up a bit an removed the extra code. New to JS and need to work on my readability!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem with the events being fired twice. I was looking at the page though a cached pre-compiled version of my app in the browser. After cleaning the assets with rake assets:clean, and holding down the shift key when refreshing the page, the JS started working normally.